# How to fix this "if" statement?

Tags: if-statement

The problem is that when the answer is null, it should show as "lollie or flavour did not enter", but it is not working.

```
var lollie;
var flavour;

lollie = prompt("Please enter type of lollie", "");
if (lollie != null) { 
   document.writeln("<p>lollie);
} else {
   document.writeln(lollie = "lollie was not entered");
}
flavour = prompt("Please enter flavour", "");
if (flavour != null) { 
   document.writeln("<p> flavour <p>");
} else {
   document.writeln(flavour = "You did not enter flavour");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `&&` (logical *AND*) instead of `||` (logical *OR*):

```js
var firstname;
var lastname;
var height;

firstname = prompt("Please enter first name of player 1", "");
if (firstname != null && firstname != "") {
  document.writeln("<td>" + firstname + "</td>");
} else {
  document.writeln(firstname = "First name not supplied");
}

lastname = prompt("Please enter Last name of player 1", "");
if (lastname != null && lastname != "") {
  document.writeln("<td>" + lastname + "</td>");
} else {
  document.writeln(lastname = "Last name not supplied");
}

height = prompt("Please enter height of player 1", "");
if (height != null && height != "") {
  document.writeln("<td>" + height + "</td>");
} else {
  document.writeln(height = "Height not supplied");
}
```

You'll also need to work a bit on your HTML markup, but I guess that is a Work In Progress.

Answer (score 0):

Delete

```
firstname != ""
```

Only write this in if statement:

```
 if(firstname !=null)
```

Answer (score 0):

use `&&` in your condition. and make sure you **trim** those variables.